# Static site on S3, DNS in Route53, error on CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am moving several sites to S3 to host them as static sites and have moved DNS here as well. I followed the AWS guide step by step, but continually get an error on the CNAME setup for WWW. Here is my setup:

1. Created bucket jeremyandlauren.com and set up static hosting and permissions.
2. Endpoint is now jeremyandlauren.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com and this works fine.
3. Pointed nameservers for this domain to Route 53.
4. Created an A record pointing to the Alias Target jeremyandlauren.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
5. Created a CNAME pointing www to jeremyandlauren.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

Now when you hit the URL either with or without www you get:

```
Code: NoSuchBucket 
Message: The specified bucket does not exist 
BucketName: www.jeremyandlauren.com
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I have tried a couple options for the CNAME, but nothing seems to take.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jeremyandlauren.com works, however, www.jeremyandlauren.com does not work.  The reason you are probably running into this is that your DNS name needs to match your bucket name.  You probably do not have a bucket with the name of www.jeremyandlauren.com.  There are two way easy ways to fix this.

1. Create a bucket www.jeremyandlauren.com and redirect it to jeremyandlauren.com. (More info here: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/04/web-page-redirects-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/)
2. Create a CloudFront distribution with the origin of jeremyandlauren.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  Add www.jeremyandlauren.com & jeremyandlauren.com as a CNAME.  Update DNS for www.jeremyandlauren.com & jeremyandlauren.com to be an A type alias to your CloudFront Distribution.
3. Keep both www.jeremyandlauren.com & jeremyandlauren.com buckets in sync with the same data.

Comment: Would it be better to create the buckets as www.jeremyandlauren.com then and would there be away to map jeremyandlauren.com over to that? I would prefer to just have one bucket obviously just to keep it manageable. This is just one of many sites, so using this as my template and can definitely move things around. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a way to do the mapping in S3.  Sounds like you would want to go with option 2 then.  CloudFront would pretty much do the same thing you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me - both with and without the 'www' if its not working for you, it may be because your dns is cached locally, or the propagation has just not made it to your servers yet - give it time.

If you are using chrome you can try clearing your local dns cache:

Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button.

Comment: It is definitely not working on my end and have tried this off multiple machines. Is it really working for you?

Comment: Yes, I can see your site at all three locations: the www, without www and then at the s3 location - all look identical. I think you may just need to wait for the DNS to propogate for you.

Comment: Cool thanks, anyway you can do a dig on it and see what the results are? (dig +recurse +trace www.jeremyandlauren.com any) No worries if not, it would just help with troubleshooting, DNS should be propagated by now...

Comment: Well now the www no longer works - did you change something? #1 in @imperialix's answer should solve that for you.